# Or'ing boolean arrays of different sizes

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy, multidimensional-array

I have 3 1-d boolean arrays:

```
a1 = np.ones((2,), dtype=bool)
a2 = np.ones((4,), dtype=bool)
a3 = np.ones((3,), dtype=bool)

a1[1]= False
a2[1:3] = False
a3[1:] = False
```

> a1 => [ True False]
>   a2 => [ True False False True]
>   a3 => [ True False False]

What I want is a new ndarray that is the shape `len(a1), len(a2), len(a3)` by or'ing the elements of the individual arrays together so that the result is:

```
[[[ True  True  True]
  [ True  True  True]
  [ True  True  True]
  [ True  True  True]]

 [[ True  True  True]
  [ True False False]
  [ True False False]
  [ True  True  True]]]
```

Is there an efficient way to do this (preferably with numpy routines)?

Comment: So to be clear, you want `result[i, j, k] == a1[i] | a2[j] | a3[k]`?

Comment: @mgilson yes exactly.

Comment: I think there's a typo with the declaration of your first array.  It should have two elements, not one.

Comment: @rayryeng indeed there was.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you just need to judiciously insert new axes and let broadcasting handle the rest:

```
>>> a1 = np.ones((2,), dtype=bool)
>>> a2 = np.ones((4,), dtype=bool)
>>> a3 = np.ones((3,), dtype=bool)
>>> 
>>> a1[1]= False
>>> a2[1:3] = False
>>> a3[1:] = False
>>>
>>> a1[:, None, None] | a2[None, :, None] | a3[None, None, :]
array([[[ True,  True,  True],
        [ True,  True,  True],
        [ True,  True,  True],
        [ True,  True,  True]],

       [[ True,  True,  True],
        [ True, False, False],
        [ True, False, False],
        [ True,  True,  True]]], dtype=bool)
```

---

If you prefer the way `np.newaxis` reads better, you can use it instead of `None` (it's an alias):

```
>>> a1[:, np.newaxis, np.newaxis] | a2[np.newaxis, :, np.newaxis] | a3[np.newaxis, np.newaxis, :]
array([[[ True,  True,  True],
        [ True,  True,  True],
        [ True,  True,  True],
        [ True,  True,  True]],

       [[ True,  True,  True],
        [ True, False, False],
        [ True, False, False],
        [ True,  True,  True]]], dtype=bool)
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a brute-force implementation that I am hoping to improve upon:

```
a1 = np.ones((2,), dtype=bool)
a2 = np.ones((4,), dtype=bool)
a3 = np.ones((3,), dtype=bool)

a1[1] = False
a2[1:3] = False
a3[1:] = False

r = np.empty((len(a1), len(a2), len(a3)), bool)

for index in np.ndindex(len(a1), len(lats), len(lons)):
    r[index] = a1[index[0]] | a2[index[1]] | a3[index[2]]

r

print(a1)
print(a2)
print(a3)
print(r)
```

Result:

```
[ True False]
[ True False False True]
[ True False False]
[[[ True  True  True]
  [ True  True  True]
  [ True  True  True]
  [ True  True  True]]

 [[ True  True  True]
  [ True False False]
  [ True False False]
  [ True  True  True]]]
```